# Google chart/Visualization api Interpolate Null is possible for some data points only?

Tags: charts, google-api, google-visualization

i have implemented a google chart api like as follows

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  data.addColumn('number', 'Year');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
  data.addColumn('number', 'Val 1');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Val 2');

  data.addRows([
  [2008,' ', 20, 15],
  [2008.5,' ', null, null],
  [2009,' ', 25, null],
  [2009.5,' ', null, null],
  [2010,' ', 30,33],
  [2010.5,' ', null, null],
  [2011,' ', 23, 38],
  ]); 

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  var ac = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  ac.draw(data, {
    title : 'Google Chart api',
    interpolateNulls: false,
    vAxis: {},
    hAxis: {
            ticks:[{v: 2008, f: '2008'},{v: 2009, f: '2009'},{v: 2010, f: '2010'},{v: 2011, f: '2011'}]
           },

    seriesType: "bars",
    series: {0: {type: "line"},1: {type: "line"}}
  });
}
```

**​actual chart**

[image: actual chart]

having tick marks that's why i added data points with decimal values (2008.5, 2009.5 ...)
and i have data points for lines on year values like 2008, 2009, 2010 ... only.

If i set InterpolateNulls : true, means it connects the data points otherwise every data points are not connected and displayed autonomous.

so can i set interpolateNulls : true for some data points or some columns only in google chart api?

**expected chart**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Edit: new answer, old one doesn't work (yet?)]**

The LineChart connects points based on adjacency in the DataTable, not adjacency in value, so you can rearrange your data to have nulls where you need them, and avoid them where you do not:

```
data.addRows([
    // set annotations
    [2008, ' ', null, null],
    [2008.5, ' ', null, null],
    [2009, ' ', null, null],
    [2009.5, ' ', null, null],
    [2010, ' ', null, null],
    [2010.5, ' ', null, null],
    [2011, ' ', null, null],
    // "Val 1" should be connected with a line, so we don't want this to have any null gaps
    [2008, null, 20, null],
    [2009, null, 25, null],
    [2010, null, 30, null],
    [2011, null, 23, null],
    // the last two points on "Val 2" should be connected, but not the first
    [2008, null, null, 15],
    [null, null, null, null], // this line of nulls will break the connection between the first and second data points
    [2010, null, null, 33],
    [2011, null, null, 38],
]);
```

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/LXkee/

**[old answer, for reference]**

You can set `interpolateNulls` on a series-by-series basis, using the `series.<series index>.interpolateNulls` option:

```
series: {
    0: {
        type: "line",
        interpolateNulls: true
    },
    1: {
        type: "line"
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution doesn't affected. Kindly run and check the code again.

Comment: but it doesn't seems to work for me, any example or other way to do this?

Comment: Hmm, that's odd.  I thought the devs had implemented this, but apparently I was wrong.  There is another approach you can take, I'll update my answer.

Comment: thank u @asgallant it works, and we need one more thing to do, we have to show tick marks upto current year if suppose data points not avail for current year also...

Comment: You'll have to add them to your data set.